# Sometimes white background goes transparent on whole page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to use this kind of  Photo Collage on my Website: [Seamless Photo Collage by AutomaticImageMontage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69lFb.jpg)
so I downloaded it and pasted the code to my Website..

it  works but sometimes when the page loads the white background  goes transparent on the whole page [transperent background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUV4p.jpg)
I'm using Parallax and Bootstrap, sometimes the parallax isn't working properly too.

I have tried to set the background to white in CSS but nothing.. sometimes it loads normally but sometimes goes transparent,

I have checked the console too but it showes only

```
jquery.montage.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
```

now i really dont have any idea how to fix it.
please help :(

**Javascript** **CSS** **and HTML**

```js
(function(window, $, undefined) {
    Array.max = function(array) {
        return Math.max.apply(Math, array)
    };
    Array.min = function(array) {
        return Math.min.apply(Math, array)
    };
    var $event = $.event,
        resizeTimeout;
    $event.special.smartresize = {
        setup: function() {
            $(this).bind("resize", $event.special.smartresize.handler)
        },
        teardown: function() {
            $(this).unbind("resize", $event.special.smartresize.handler)
        },
        handler: function(event, execAsap) {
            var context = this,
                args = arguments;
            event.type = "smartresize";
            if (resizeTimeout) {
                clearTimeout(resizeTimeout)
            }
            resizeTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                jQuery.event.handle.apply(context, args)
            }, execAsap === "execAsap" ? 0 : 50)
        }
    };
    $.fn.smartresize = function(fn) {
        return fn ? this.bind("smartresize", fn) : this.trigger("smartresize", ["execAsap"])
    };
    $.fn.imagesLoaded = function(callback) {
        var $images = this.find('img'),
            len = $images.length,
            _this = this,
            blank = 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw==';

        function triggerCallback() {
            callback.call(_this, $images)
        }

        function imgLoaded() {
            if (--len <= 0 && this.src !== blank) {
                setTimeout(triggerCallback);
                $images.unbind('load error', imgLoaded)
            }
        }
        if (!len) {
            triggerCallback()
        }
        $images.bind('load error', imgLoaded).each(function() {
            if (this.complete || this.complete === undefined) {
                var src = this.src;
                this.src = blank;
                this.src = src
            }
        });
        return this
    };
    $.Montage = function(options, element) {
        this.element = $(element).show();
        this.cache = {};
        this.heights = new Array();
        this._create(options)
    };
    $.Montage.defaults = {
        liquid: true,
        margin: 1,
        minw: 70,
        minh: 20,
        maxh: 250,
        alternateHeight: false,
        alternateHeightRange: {
            min: 100,
            max: 300
        },
        fixedHeight: null,
        minsize: false,
        fillLastRow: false
    };
    $.Montage.prototype = {
        _getImageWidth: function($img, h) {
            var i_w = $img.width(),
                i_h = $img.height(),
                r_i = i_h / i_w;
            return Math.ceil(h / r_i)
        },
        _getImageHeight: function($img, w) {
            var i_w = $img.width(),
                i_h = $img.height(),
                r_i = i_h / i_w;
            return Math.ceil(r_i * w)
        },
        _chooseHeight: function() {
            if (this.options.minsize) {
                return Array.min(this.heights)
            }
            var result = {},
                max = 0,
                res, val, min;
            for (var i = 0, total = this.heights.length; i < total; ++i) {
                var val = this.heights[i],
                    inc = (result[val] || 0) + 1;
                if (val < this.options.minh || val > this.options.maxh) continue;
                result[val] = inc;
                if (inc >= max) {
                    max = inc;
                    res = val
                }
            }
            for (var i in result) {
                if (result[i] === max) {
                    val = i;
                    min = min || val;
                    if (min < this.options.minh) min = null;
                    else if (min > val) min = val;
                    if (min === null) min = val
                }
            }
            if (min === undefined) min = this.heights[0];
            res = min;
            return res
        },
        _stretchImage: function($img) {
            var prevWrapper_w = $img.parent().width(),
                new_w = prevWrapper_w + this.cache.space_w_left,
                crop = {
                    x: new_w,
                    y: this.theHeight
                };
            var new_image_w = $img.width() + this.cache.space_w_left,
                new_image_h = this._getImageHeight($img, new_image_w);
            this._cropImage($img, new_image_w, new_image_h, crop);
            this.cache.space_w_left = this.cache.container_w;
            if (this.options.alternateHeight) this.theHeight = Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.options.alternateHeightRange.max - this.options.alternateHeightRange.min + 1) + this.options.alternateHeightRange.min)
        },
        _updatePrevImage: function($nextimg) {
            var $prevImage = this.element.find('img.montage:last');
            this._stretchImage($prevImage);
            this._insertImage($nextimg)
        },
        _insertImage: function($img) {
            var new_w = this._getImageWidth($img, this.theHeight);
            if (this.options.minsize && !this.options.alternateHeight) {
                if (this.cache.space_w_left <= this.options.margin * 2) {
                    this._updatePrevImage($img)
                } else {
                    if (new_w > this.cache.space_w_left) {
                        var crop = {
                            x: this.cache.space_w_left,
                            y: this.theHeight
                        };
                        this._cropImage($img, new_w, this.theHeight, crop);
                        this.cache.space_w_left = this.cache.container_w;
                        $img.addClass('montage')
                    } else {
                        var crop = {
                            x: new_w,
                            y: this.theHeight
                        };
                        this._cropImage($img, new_w, this.theHeight, crop);
                        this.cache.space_w_left -= new_w;
                        $img.addClass('montage')
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (new_w < this.options.minw) {
                    if (this.options.minw > this.cache.space_w_left) {
                        this._updatePrevImage($img)
                    } else {
                        var new_w = this.options.minw,
                            new_h = this._getImageHeight($img, new_w),
                            crop = {
                                x: new_w,
                                y: this.theHeight
                            };
                        this._cropImage($img, new_w, new_h, crop);
                        this.cache.space_w_left -= new_w;
                        $img.addClass('montage')
                    }
                } else {
                    if (new_w > this.cache.space_w_left && this.cache.space_w_left < this.options.minw) {
                        this._updatePrevImage($img)
                    } else if (new_w > this.cache.space_w_left && this.cache.space_w_left >= this.options.minw) {
                        var crop = {
                            x: this.cache.space_w_left,
                            y: this.theHeight
                        };
                        this._cropImage($img, new_w, this.theHeight, crop);
                        this.cache.space_w_left = this.cache.container_w;
                        if (this.options.alternateHeight) this.theHeight = Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.options.alternateHeightRange.max - this.options.alternateHeightRange.min + 1) + this.options.alternateHeightRange.min);
                        $img.addClass('montage')
                    } else {
                        var crop = {
                            x: new_w,
                            y: this.theHeight
                        };
                        this._cropImage($img, new_w, this.theHeight, crop);
                        this.cache.space_w_left -= new_w;
                        $img.addClass('montage')
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        _cropImage: function($img, w, h, cropParam) {
            var dec = this.options.margin * 2;
            var $wrapper = $img.parent('a');
            this._resizeImage($img, w, h);
            $img.css({
                left: -(w - cropParam.x) / 2 + 'px',
                top: -(h - cropParam.y) / 2 + 'px'
            });
            $wrapper.addClass('am-wrapper').css({
                width: cropParam.x - dec + 'px',
                height: cropParam.y + 'px',
                margin: this.options.margin
            })
        },
        _resizeImage: function($img, w, h) {
            $img.css({
                width: w + 'px',
                height: h + 'px'
            })
        },
        _reload: function() {
            var new_el_w = this.element.width();
            if (new_el_w !== this.cache.container_w) {
                this.element.hide();
                this.cache.container_w = new_el_w;
                this.cache.space_w_left = new_el_w;
                var instance = this;
                instance.$imgs.removeClass('montage').each(function(i) {
                    instance._insertImage($(this))
                });
                if (instance.options.fillLastRow && instance.cache.space_w_left !== instance.cache.container_w) {
                    instance._stretchImage(instance.$imgs.eq(instance.totalImages - 1))
                }
                instance.element.show()
            }
        },
        _create: function(options) {
            this.options = $.extend(true, {}, $.Montage.defaults, options);
            var instance = this,
                el_w = instance.element.width();
            instance.$imgs = instance.element.find('img');
            instance.totalImages = instance.$imgs.length;
            if (instance.options.liquid) $('html').css('overflow-y', 'scroll');
            if (!instance.options.fixedHeight) {
                instance.$imgs.each(function(i) {
                    var $img = $(this),
                        img_w = $img.width();
                    if (img_w < instance.options.minw && !instance.options.minsize) {
                        var new_h = instance._getImageHeight($img, instance.options.minw);
                        instance.heights.push(new_h)
                    } else {
                        instance.heights.push($img.height())
                    }
                })
            }
            instance.theHeight = (!instance.options.fixedHeight && !instance.options.alternateHeight) ? instance._chooseHeight() : instance.options.fixedHeight;
            if (instance.options.alternateHeight) instance.theHeight = Math.floor(Math.random() * (instance.options.alternateHeightRange.max - instance.options.alternateHeightRange.min + 1) + instance.options.alternateHeightRange.min);
            instance.cache.container_w = el_w;
            instance.cache.space_w_left = el_w;
            instance.$imgs.each(function(i) {
                instance._insertImage($(this))
            });
            if (instance.options.fillLastRow && instance.cache.space_w_left !== instance.cache.container_w) {
                instance._stretchImage(instance.$imgs.eq(instance.totalImages - 1))
            }
            $(window).bind('smartresize.montage', function() {
                instance._reload()
            })
        },
        add: function($images, callback) {
            var $images_stripped = $images.find('img');
            this.$imgs = this.$imgs.add($images_stripped);
            this.totalImages = this.$imgs.length;
            this._add($images, callback)
        },
        _add: function($images, callback) {
            var instance = this;
            $images.find('img').each(function(i) {
                instance._insertImage($(this))
            });
            if (instance.options.fillLastRow && instance.cache.space_w_left !== instance.cache.container_w) instance._stretchImage(instance.$imgs.eq(instance.totalImages - 1));
            if (callback) callback.call($images)
        },
        destroy: function(callback) {
            this._destroy(callback)
        },
        _destroy: function(callback) {
            this.$imgs.removeClass('montage').css({
                position: '',
                width: '',
                height: '',
                left: '',
                top: ''
            }).unwrap();
            if (this.options.liquid) $('html').css('overflow', '');
            this.element.unbind('.montage').removeData('montage');
            $(window).unbind('.montage');
            if (callback) callback.call()
        },
        option: function(key, value) {
            if ($.isPlainObject(key)) {
                this.options = $.extend(true, this.options, key)
            }
        }
    };
    var logError = function(message) {
        if (this.console) {
            console.error(message)
        }
    };
    $.fn.montage = function(options) {
        if (typeof options === 'string') {
            var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
            this.each(function() {
                var instance = $.data(this, 'montage');
                if (!instance) {
                    logError("cannot call methods on montage prior to initialization; " + "attempted to call method '" + options + "'");
                    return
                }
                if (!$.isFunction(instance[options]) || options.charAt(0) === "_") {
                    logError("no such method '" + options + "' for montage instance");
                    return
                }
                instance[options].apply(instance, args)
            })
        } else {
            this.each(function() {
                var instance = $.data(this, 'montage');
                if (instance) {
                    instance.option(options || {});
                    instance._reload()
                } else {
                    $.data(this, 'montage', new $.Montage(options, this))
                }
            })
        }
        return this
    }
})(window, jQuery);
```

```css
.am-wrapper{
 float:left;
 position:relative;
 overflow:hidden;
}
.am-wrapper img{
 position:absolute;
 outline:none;
}
```

```html
      <div class="container">
        <div id="am-container" class="am-container"><a href="#"><img src="images/1.jpg"></a><a href="#"><img src="images/2.jpg"></a><a href="#"><img src="images/3.jpg"></a><a href="#"><img src="images/4.jpg"></a><a href="#"><img src="images/5.jpg"></a><a href="#"><img src="images/6.jpg"></a><a href="#"><img src="images/7.jpg"></a><a href="#"><img src="images/8.jpg"></a><a href="#"><img src="images/9.jpg"></a><a href="#"><img src="images/10.jpg"></a><a href="#"><img src="images/11.jpg"></a><a href="#"><img src="images/12.jpg"></a><a href="#"><img src="images/13.jpg"></a><a href="#"><img src="images/14.jpg"></a><a href="#"><img src="images/15.jpg"></a><a href="#"><img src="images/16.jpg"></a><a href="#"><img src="images/17.jpg"></a><a href="#"><img src="images/18.jpg"></a><a href="#"><img src="images/19.jpg"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
        var $container  = $('#am-container'),
        $imgs  = $container.find('img').hide(),
        totalImgs = $imgs.length,
        cnt   = 0;
        $imgs.each(function(i) {
        var $img = $(this);
        $('<img/>').load(function() {
        ++cnt;
        if( cnt === totalImgs ) {
        $imgs.show();
        $container.montage({
        fillLastRow    : false,
        alternateHeight   : false,
        alternateHeightRange : {
        min : 90,
        max : 100
        }
        });
        }
        }).attr('src',$img.attr('src'));
        });
        });
      </script>
```

Comment: What is `jQuery.event.handle`, I've never seen that before. Maybe it should be`.handlers`?

Comment: i have solved the `jquery.montage.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined` .. Jquery.event.handle was not documented and removed in the 1.9 JQuery version .. i have replaced it with `$(this).trigger(event, [args]);`.. but the background is still going transparent :/